# bash: extract executed line numbers from gcov report

Tags: regex, bash, sed, gcov

`gcov` is a GNU toolchain utility that produces code coverage reports (see [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html)) formated as follows:

```
    -:    0:Source:../../../edg/attribute.c
    -:    0:Graph:tmp.gcno
    -:    0:Data:tmp.gcda
    -:    0:Runs:1
    -:    0:Programs:1
    -:    1:#include <stdio.h>
    -:    2:
    -:    3:int main (void)
    1:    4:{
    1:    5:  int i, total;
    -:    6:
    1:    7:  total = 0;
    -:    8:
   11:    9:  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   10:   10:    total += i;
    -:   11:
    1:   12:  if (total != 45)
#####:   13:    printf ("Failure\n");
    -:   14:  else
    1:   15:    printf ("Success\n");
    1:   16:  return 0;
    -:   17:}
```

I need to extract the line numbers of the lines that were executed from a bash script. `$ egrep --regexp='^\s+[1-9]' example_file.c.gcov` seems to return the relevant lines. An exemple of typical output would be:

```
    1:  978:  attr_name_map = alloc_hash_table(NO_MEMORY_REGION_NUMBER,
   79:  982:  for (k = 0; k<KNOWN_ATTR_TABLE_LENGTH; ++k) {
   78:  989:    attr_name_map_entries[k].descr = &known_attr_table[k];
   78:  990:    *ep = &attr_name_map_entries[k];
    1:  992:}  /* init_attr_name_map */
  519: 2085:      new_attr_seen = FALSE;
  519: 2103:      p_attributes = last_attribute_link(p_attributes);
  519: 2104:    } while (new_attr_seen);
  519: 2106:  return attributes;
   16: 3026:void transform_type_with_gnu_attributes(a_type_ptr        *p_type,
   16: 3041:  for (ap = attributes; ap != NULL; ap = ap->next) {
    1: 6979:void process_alias_fixup_list(void)
    1: 6984:  an_alias_fixup_ptr  entries = alias_fixup_list, entry;
```

I subsequently must extract the line number strings.  The expected output from this example would be:

```
978
982
989
990
992
2085
2103
2104
2106
3026
3041
6979
6984
```

Could someone suggest a reliable, robust way to achieve this?

---

**NOTE:** 
My idea was to eliminate everything that is not placed between the first and the second instance of the character `:`, which I tried to do with `sed` without much success so far.

Comment: If you're okay with bash-specific code, parameter expansion would do this faster than sed/awk/etc other external processes/programs. `example="123: 456: 789abc#\$&-+)({}\/"; example="${example#*\:}"; echo "${example%\:*}";` outputs: 456 (tested as a one-liner, needs a for loop for the list).

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple to do using `awk`:

```
awk -F: '/ +[0-9]/ {gsub(/ /, "", $2); print $2}' file.gcov
```

That is, use `:` as the field separator,
and for lines starting with spaces and digits,
replace the spaces from the 2nd field and print the 2nd field.

But if you really want to use `sed`,
and you want something robust, you could do this:

```
sed -e '/^  *[0-9][0-9]*:  *[0-9][0-9]*:/!d' -e 's/[^:]*: *//' -e 's/:.*//' file.gcov
```

What's happening here?

- The first command uses a pattern to match lines starting with 1 or more spaces followed by 1 or more digits followed by a `:` followed by 1 or more spaces followed by 1 or more digits followed by a `:`. Then comes the interesting part, we invert this selection with `!` and delete it with `d`. We effectively delete all other lines except the ones we need.
- The second command is a simple substitution, replacing a sequence of characters that are not `:` followed by a `:` followed by zero or more spaces. The pattern is applied from the beginning of the line so no need for a starting `^`, and no need to specify strictly 1-or-more-spaces, thanks to the previous command we already know that there will be at least one.
- The last command is even simpler, replace a `:` and everything after it.

Some versions of `sed` will give you shortcuts for a more compact writing style, for example `[0-9]+` instead of `[0-9][0-9]*`, but the example above will work with a wider variety of implementations (notably BSD).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Janos, I haven't tried it as of yet but at first glance it seems good. Which do you think would perform fastest of your or mine solution?

Comment: @J.Doe generally the fewer processes in the pipeline, the better. So one awk/sed should be better than egrep + sed. Also, although you say you like `[:]` instead of `:`, it might create extra work for the regex parser (or not, maybe it's smart enough to transparently convert to `:` either way)